# Is it dangerous to allow people to use <script> tags in forum posts?

Tags: javascript, widget

We want to allow people to embed some widgets sometimes in our forum posts. But we have been stripping out script tags because of a sense of security concern, even though we don't really know what the concerns are.

There are zillions of useful widgets out there, and we don't mind people adding them in general to posts, but we don't want to compromise our system, or allow for trojans, etc.

What do people think these days? Is our practice of disallowing script tags considered the best practice?

Thanks,

doug

Comment: In short, never allow `<script>` tag to be entered freely by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How dangerous?  Very.  Letting people embed <script> tags in posts is an open invitation for [cross-site scripting attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Thanks. What I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally inadvisable to allow your users to embed their own (untrusted) JavaScript logic into your page, particularly if you are going to store that information in your database and allow other people to access it. Opening up your site to user-embedded `<script>` tags is a common source of XSS attacks, also known as cross-site scripting attacks. You should check out this [cheatsheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more info.

Cross-site scripting attacks take to form of malicious JS code that is embedded into your page by a third-party with the purpose of hijacking some portion of your site. As an example, imagine a user embeds a script that creates what appears to be a widget on your site (let's say it's a weather widget), except that when the user clicks on a specific day's weather, they are redirected to a malicious site.

If you feel you simply **must** allow your users this functionality, consider creating a *whitelist* of widgets from a trusted party (i.e. Wordpress, Google, Twitter) and allowing your users to select from your whitelisted widgets. This gives you the necessary control over your production environment while simultaneously giving your site more rich content.

Comment: Thanks to you too. So to whom do I credit the correct answer since you are both right? :)